# rd /s /q does not behave silently when it should?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm running `rd /s /q  D:\TestWebServer\` in a simple batch file on Windows Server 2019.

The documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/rd) says the toggle /q is silent mode and the entire directory tree is deleted without confirmation.

Yet if a folder is present in `D:\TestWebServer\` the cmd hangs at "are you sure Y/N" ???

[image: Screen shot of the user input]

Am I using `rd /s/q` correctly? or am I missing something else?

My goal is just to delete all files and folders from `D:\TestWebServer\`.

This is the whole script in case something else is causing the problem:

```
ForFiles /p "D:\TestWebServer" /s /d -0 /c "cmd /c del @file"
rd /s /q  D:\TestWebServer\ 
xcopy "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\README.txt" "D:\TestWebServer\*.*"
xcopy "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\web.config" "D:\TestWebServer\*.*"
```

Comment: The error message indicates that the `rd` command has not yet being reached...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the script you've shared you've not used the quiet switch with del command

```
del @file /s
```

so that's why it's asking you confirmation.

Also, instead of this long process, you could just use

```
rd /s /q D:\TestWebServer
```

it'll work. I didn't even understand why you wanted the files to come with date-sorting

```
rd /d -0
```

as you're deleting all the files regardless.

Hope this helps